# How to sort values of textboxes in vb?

Tags: vb.net

I have two groups of textboxes, A and B and these are created dynamically.

My program should work like this:
1. A textboxes have corresponding B textboxes.
2. Then, B textboxes should be sorted by their values in ascending order.
3. Based on that order, the A textboxes' values will be sorted also.

EX:

```
A                   B
5                   1
2                   0
3                   4
1                   5
```

Output is:     2  5  3  1

Please help me out. Thanks!

Comment: What exactly are you expecting to happen?  Do you want the values in the TextBoxes rearranged or do you just want to display a list of values in a message box for example?

Comment: uhmm.. i want the values to be displayed in labels. Example:  label1's text is 2, label2's text is 5 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Create arrays of the textbox controls you have and then write a simple bubble sort. Bubble sort is slow, but more than fast enough for small amounts of data.

```
Dim arrA() As Textbox = {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5}
Dim arrB() As Textbox = {b1, b2, b3, b4, b5}
Dim Changed as Boolean
Do
  Changed = False
  For i = 0 to arrB.Count - 2 'Stop at the second to last array item because we check forward in the array
    If CInt(arrB(i).Text) > CInt(arrB(i + 1).Text) Then 'Next value is smaller than previous --> Switch values, also switch in arrA
      Dim Temp as String = arrB(i + 1).Text
      arrB(i + 1).Text = arrB(i).Text
      arrB(i).Text = Temp
      Temp = arrA(i + 1).Text
      arrA(i + 1).Text = arrA(i).Text
      arrA(i).Text = Temp
      Changed = True
    End If
  Next
Loop Until Changed = False 'Cancle the loop when everything is sorted
```

Now the textbox values are sorted and you can display the results whereever you want.

To display the values in the labels, say called l1-l5:

```
Dim arrL() as Label = {l1, l2, l3, l4, l5}
For i = 0 to 4
  arrL(i).Text = arrA(i).Text
Next
```