# Textbox values sorting

Tags: vb.net

I have two groups of textboxes, A and B and these are created dynamically.

My program should work like this: 1. A textboxes have corresponding B textboxes. 2. Then, B textboxes should be sorted by their values in ascending order. 3. Based on that order, the A textboxes' values will be sorted also.

Input:
[image]

Output:
[image]

Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: possible **exact** duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22317571/how-to-sort-values-of-textboxes-in-vb

Comment: Don't post the same question multiple times.

Comment: I'm sorry. We're groupmates by the way, the other user who asked the same question, that is. I've included pictures here. This is what we want to happen.

Comment: Are the values in the text boxes limited to integers, how are the left text box pairs stored in your code?

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved relatively easily with LINQ which provides an [OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method for sorting, and a [Zip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method for aligning the As with the Bs.

Assuming TextBox arrays inputAs, inputBs, outputAs and outputBs:

```
Private Sub Sort_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Sort.Click        
    ' Zip A and B inputs and extract values
    Dim inputs =
        inputAs.Zip(inputBs,
                    Function(a, b) New With {.A = CInt(a.Text), .B = CInt(b.Text)})

    ' Sort values by B
    Dim values = inputs.OrderBy(Function(item) item.B).ToArray()

    ' Set outputs with sorted input values
    For i = 0 To values.Length - 1
        outputAs(i).Text = values(i).A.ToString()
        outputBs(i).Text = values(i).B.ToString()
    Next
End Sub
```

To sort with the labels too, the B values can be sorted along with their corresponding ordinals, and then the ordinals used to copy from the input controls to the output controls:

```
Private Sub Sort_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
    Handles Sort.Click
    ' Map Bs to collection of ordinals and values
    ' Then order by values
    Dim items =
        InputBs _
            .Select(Function(control, i) _
                    New With _
                    {.Ordinal = i,
                     .Value = CInt(control.Text)}) _
            .OrderBy(Function(item) item.Value) _
            .ToArray()

    ' Set outputs with sorted input values        
    For i = 0 To items.Length - 1
        Dim j = items(i).Ordinal
        OutputAs(j).Text = InputAs(i).Text
        OutputBs(j).Text = InputBs(i).Text
        OutputLabels(j).Text = InputLabels(i).Text
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Like This

First Create Array Variable and Pass the `A Texbox Value's`, And create another array variable and pass `B Textbox Value's`. After that doing like this

```
 Dim xaTexBoxValue() As Integer = {5, 6, 4, 2} // A Text Box Values
        Dim xBTextBoxValue() As Integer = {10, 3, 23, 50} // B Text Box Values
        Dim xTemp As Integer = 0

        For xi As Integer = 0 To xaTexBoxValue.Count - 1

            For xj As Integer = xi + 1 To xaTexBoxValue.Count - 1

                If xaTexBoxValue(xj) < xaTexBoxValue(xi) Then
                    xTemp = xaTexBoxValue(xi)
                    xaTexBoxValue(xi) = xaTexBoxValue(xj)
                    xaTexBoxValue(xj) = xTemp

                    xTemp = xBTextBoxValue(xi)
                    xBTextBoxValue(xi) = xBTextBoxValue(xj)
                    xBTextBoxValue(xj) = xTemp

                End If

            Next

        Next
```

After this function pass this value to textbox's

Comment: how to pass the values to the textboxes?

Comment: what is your textbox names

Comment: Sir,i already figured that out. By the way, have you noticed the letters beside the Set B textboxes? How can i make it arranged to together with the values sorted? Please see the pictures please. I really need to find how that thing should be done.

Comment: @SmashedPotato. the letter is are show in labels ah?. and I want to textbox's names or assign the array value in order of showing textbox's